# libpthread version mismatch on HP_UX

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, hp-ux

I have multithreaded application, it is working fine at my development server (HP-UX). When it is deployed to client server it gives the following error:

```
. Process 16448. Starting (CONT) Thread: 0    /usr/lib/pa20_64/dld.sl:
 Unsatisfied code ymbol 'pthread_create' in load module 'bin/CCQO'.
    Killed
```

I fond that libpthread.1 at customer server does not have pthread_create method with nm command. This from client server:

```
/usr/lib/pa20_64 > nm -g libpthread.1 | grep 'pthread_cre'

    [475]    |   4611686018427436512|    1116|FUNC |GLOB |0|.text|__pthread_create_system
```

But when I run the same command on my development server I get following output:

```
[733]    |   4611686018427467256|    2160|FUNC |GLOB |0| .text|__pthread_create_generic
[712]    |   4611686018427467192|      64|FUNC |GLOB |0| .text|__pthread_create_system
[625]    |   4611686018427467112|      64|FUNC |WEAK |0| .text|pthread_create
```

I tried to copy libraries from my server to client server but it does not work.

Please me know how can I now the version of threading library at my machine and at client machine ?

How can I update client machine with updated library ?

Can copying my libraries to other server, solve the issue ? If yes, then what are steps.

Answer (score 1):

> I fond that libpthread.1 at customer server does not have pthread_create method with nm command.

Your customer's `libpthread.1` is corrupt. Perhaps the customer ran `strip`, or molested it in some other way.

> Can copying my libraries to other server, solve the issue ?

This can render the machine un-bootable, and you should almost certainly *not* do that.

The right solution is for the customer's sysadmin to restore system libraries from his HP-UX media.